# How to version control CMS content (e.g. Drupal), given that we use git for code

Tags: database, git, content-management-system, workflow

what is the best git workflow for web development team who use cms? Let me explain the situation.
In our last project we moved to git for version control.

First we tried distributed version control, where each member had each own git repo and pushed/pulled to a bare repo. However, since we used Drupal (*but Druapl not the only cms that does it*) we relied on modules. When creating a layout of a page Drupal(module) will generate it's own HTML, which is sent to DB.

SO the problem arisez when we push source code of the template to bare repo, the other developer can pull it but the changes of the db stay in the local db. At some point we gave up this style of workflow and started to work one a sigle server.

And on a next project we simply started to work on one server and tried to create as many templates as possible, so that those templates would over ride modules attempts to creste it's own HTML which would be sent to DB. **But my question is, did any of you have this problem and how did you solve it?**

This problem, it seems, to be specific to web development simply because of the DB.

I think this question is a generic one and not really specific to git or Druapl, it's more of a version-control-workflow with cms problem.

Comment: Well, if you have editor privileges you can just edit the question. And if you are a good programer, then give me a suggestion or a reference or an advice or an answer or anything...

Comment: [This link](http://drupal.org/node/956112), or [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893774/working-with-version-control-on-a-drupal-cms-project) are related - they might give you some ideas.

Comment: simont, you know you are on to something, you should post it as an answer. But this quote, in one of the posts you sent, says it all "The problem you're describing is still one of the biggest unresolved problems in Drupal as far as I can tell."

Comment: I tried a retitle, see what u think

Comment: Awesome, Michael. Thanks. That's way more relevant. Your title pretty much sums everything up.

Comment: @user744184 When replying to comments, use "@<name>", which will alert the comment owner of the reply (the question or answer 'owner' is automatically alerted). Database version-control related questions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364498/drupal-on-git-what-to-do-with-the-database) on SO are perhaps also useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the correct answer in the comment by **simont**:

Here are the links from the comment:

1. http://drupal.org/node/956112
2. [Working with version control on a Drupal/CMS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893774/working-with-version-control-on-a-drupal-cms-project)